# How to send an array from a front end file to a back end file? (next js 13)

Tags: javascript, post, axios, next.js13

So i have this front end file pages.js located here app\page.js.
I want to send an array of products named 'items' to app\api\stripeCheckout\route.js when i click on a button.
Then i console.log(items) to prove the opration is successful.

app\page.js

```
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const createCheckoutSession = async () => {
    const items = [
      { name: 'Product 1', price: 1000, quantity: 2 },
      { name: 'Product 2', price: 500, quantity: 1 },
    ];
    const response = await axios.post('/api/stripeCheckout', { items });
};


const CheckoutButton = () => {
  return (
    <button onClick={createCheckoutSession}>
      Create Checkout Session
    </button>
  );
};

export default CheckoutButton;
```

app\api\stripeCheckout\route.js

```
export default async function POST(req, res) {

  const { items } = req.body;

  console.log('Received items:', items);
}
```

The problem is that it result in AxiosError: Request failed with status code 405 and i don't know why.
Thanks for the help.